# "Review" long question messes up with stats shown on right

Tags: discussion, bug, design

While [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1986553) for "Close Votes", I found a bug in the page.

As the title of the question is lengthy, it crosses and messes with the labels on the right side.

Am I seeing this first, as I can't find any similar questions here?

BTW I am using a 20" monitor, Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m. OS is windows7. I checked this in FireFox and it works fine!!!.

Issue is only with Chrome...

[image]

Comment: No repro here. What browser/version?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m. OS windows7.

Comment: @Mysticial: i added the image.

Comment: Ah, I'm on FF 20.0.1, Windows 7. And it looks fine here.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome stable, Ubuntu

Comment: Then this is surely a bug, you can't have browser dependent pages, am I wrong?

Comment: Now we need someone to post a terrible question with a one word title, and have everyone swarm the "Low Quality Posts" queue. (Unfortunately, this probably won't be reproducible)

Comment: Reproduced on chrome stable mac mountain lion.. Definitely a bug